# 401 File Download Attempt With Node-Wget

Tags: node.js, selenium, phantomjs, cucumber, wget

Attempting to download a file with Node-Wget:

```
wget ({
      url: 'https://localhost...',
      dest: './test_artifacts/logs/',
      timeout: 2000
      }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('--- error:');
            console.log(error);            // error encountered 
        } else {
            console.log('--- headers:');
            console.log(response.headers); // response headers 
            console.log('--- body:');
            console.log(body);             // content of package 
        }
    }
);
```

Also, using PhantomJS, Selenium Webdriver and Cucumber.
The above code works when a file is publicly available but when I use it on my site I get:

```
Status Code: 401; Unauthorized
```

The site uses a login page to verify the user. I presume this is what is blocking my downloading of the file. At this stage in the test steps though, Selenium has already logged in and navigated through the site. This leads me to believe that Wget requires something to be passed to it to determine the user has already logged in. The problem is, the documentation for node-wget is very small and I have seen no command in docs that provides a solution.

Link to package being used:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wget

Comment: you most likely need to add an authorization header, which it looks like the node-wget package supports.  see [Authorization - HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After reading your link above, I believe I understand the concept. I am having trouble implementing it using node-wget, however.
Tried a few variations on the following header:
Authorization: 'username:password',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched over to npm 'request'. Works fine. Allows for custom http header fields such as:

```
headers: { 
Authorization: 'Bearer esdfsdf...' 
}
};
```